# Errors from async request I did not call

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, get, django-errors

I have a Django project when I visit the site, I keep getting these errors from an async request that I didn't even call.

I don't know what they are and why they are coming. I have missing elements on the page. I even cleared my cache but that didn't help. It works fine in the incognito window.

Here are the errors:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your extension currently used, blocking the request I think. Because you said it works fine in incognito window (usually extension is disabled by default). Maybe try to disable your extension would help your case

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick search and looks like this is related to one of your Google chrome extensions.  Nothing related to you code.